# Hudson context url

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, winstone

How can I change Hudson context url and access it something like http://localhost:8080/hudson instead of http://localhost:8080/? I'm using hudson standalone and is runing as a service on a fedora virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

The standalone version of hudson uses [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/) as embedded container.

You can find some Hudson-specific config notes [on the hudson wiki](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Winstone), but I guess the [Winston Sourceforge Page](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/) (section: [command line options](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#commandLine)) is the best place to look.

Edit: the actual Solution can be found on [this blog page](http://blog.yclian.com/2008/06/changing-context-path-of-hudson.html):

```
java -jar hudson.war --prefix=/hudson
```